# What's the correct way of referencing a method in a controller for running through batch processing?

Tags: 8, batch-operations

I have a set of batch operations with:

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  $test_sites[] = array('\Drupal\my_module\Controller\BatchTestSite::TestSite', $url);
}
```

When I run it I get the following:

```
Deprecated function: Non-static method Drupal\my_module\Controller\BatchTestSite::TestSite() should not be called statically in _batch_process()
```

What's the correct way of referencing a method in a controller for running through batch processing (even if it's not static)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are services and should be initiated as such. 
Either use the static `create` method to create an instance of the controller or define a service for it and use `\Drupal::service('...')`

Answer (score 1):

Drupal\my_module\Controller\BatchTestSite::TestSite is not a function but class method. You need to make it static to use as batch callback.

Comment: Potentially you could pass any callable so `[$this, 'method']` might work as well.

Comment: Maybe, but that would need to persist that object in the batch data in the database. Would be nice if batch api would support the service syntax with a single :, but you can replicate that yourself with a single line function/static method that calls the service.

Comment: I've updated my question to make be accurate (method not function). So I think what your saying @ya.teck is that it's correct even though it's throwing that warning is that right?

Comment: @digital, you missed the second part of the answer.

Comment: Controllers are services and should be initiated as such. Either use the static `create` method to create an instance of the controller or define a service for it and use `\Drupal::service('...')`

Comment: Thanks @Eyal I created a service of my controller and then passed it through that way. If you create an answer with that I'll mark is as correct.